# Passar nome da cidade vindo do JavaScript para o PHP no google maps

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso passar para o PHP o nome da cidade vindo do Javascript

Utilizo esse código para pegar o nome da cidade

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key="></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var geocoder;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction(){
    alert("Geocoder failed");
}

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



  }

  function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
        if (results[1]) {
        alert (results[0].address_components[1].short_name);



         //formatted address
     //    alert(results[0].formatted_address)
        //find country name
             for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {


            //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "locality") {
                    //this is the object you are looking for
                    city= results[0].address_components[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //city data 
        //alert(city.long_name)


        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Seria possível passar o valor de `alert (results[0].address_components[1].short_name);` para o PHP?

Comment: Quando você diz: enviar para o php, na verdade, está dizendo fazer uma requisição http usando o php, dessa forma, já tentou usar Ajax? Por exemplo, você, provavelmente, tem algum arquivo php esperando a requisição, certo?

Comment: como eu poderia colocar um Ajax dentro do Javascript? Isso seria apenas para mostrar ao usuário do site a cidade onde ele se encontra na hora que entra no site.

Comment: Entendi, vou editar a resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Exemplo básico usando Ajax:**

**Note que `seu-arquivo-php.php` é para onde você fará a requisição.**

```js
var geocoder;
//Variável Criada
var nomeCidade;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
}
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;
  codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction() {
  alert("Geocoder failed");
}

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

}

function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({
    'latLng': latlng
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
      if (results[1]) {
        //alert ();

        nomeCidade = results[0].address_components[1].short_name;
        //Mostra o nome da cidade
        document.getElementById("cidade").innerText = nomeCidade;
        enviarDadoParaPHP(`cidade_nome=${results[0].address_components[1].short_name}`);


        //formatted address
        //    alert(results[0].formatted_address)
        //find country name
        for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
          for (var b = 0; b < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; b++) {


            //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
            if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "locality") {
              //this is the object you are looking for
              city = results[0].address_components[i];
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        //city data 
        //alert(city.long_name)


      } else {
        alert("No results found");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
    }
  });
}
//Usando Ajax no Javascript
function enviarDadoParaPHP(data) {
  //Isso é AJaxa ()
  //AJAX = Assíncrono Javascript XML.
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "seu-arquivo-php.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send(data);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Demo</h1>
  <p id="cidade">Nome da Cidade Aqui</p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key="></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: como fica o arquivo php para pegar cidade?

Comment: Há várias coisas que precisamos levar em consideração. Por exemplo: se você está querendo simplesmente mostrar o nome da cidade numa página php, você pode fazer como na edição.

Comment: no seu-arquivo-php.php coloquei assim session_start();
echo $_SESSION['cidade']=$_POST['enviarDadoParaPHP']; mais nao deu certo

Comment: Tente, no seu arquivo php, o seguinte: $_SESSION['cidade']=$_POST['cidade_nome'];

Comment: deu certo ;) obrigado

Comment: Tem um probleminha ainda: Quando abro o site ele chama o arquivo php e grava na sessão   o nome da cidade corretamente, porém preciso atualizar a página novamente para ver o nome da cidade. Teria como já mostrar o nome da cidade sem precisar atualizar a página?

Comment: Sim, tem como. Se ninguém responder. Amanhã, lhe ajudo.

Comment: ok obrigado pela atenção